# How do I get the application root?

Tags: html, relative-path

The physical folder structure on my web server is:

inetpub
oo|
oo|_wwwroot
oooooo|
oooooo|_MyApp    ----> this is the root folder of my web application
oooooooooo|
oooooooooo|_images
oooooooooo|
oooooooooo|_styles
oooooooooo|
oooooooooo|_pages

I have an html file (test.html) under the pages folder. I want to link to other files (eg. stylesheets and images) via absolute paths. So, I have a line of code similar to this:

`<img src="/images/roundbutton.png" />`

When the page is rendered, the image is not displayed, as the "/" tells it to look for the image in a folder wwwroot/images.

Is there another way to use absolute paths to refer to the application root, instead of the site root? Or is using relative paths the only other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the [`<base>`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/base) element.

Comment: So, I need to include this inside the head tag?

`<base href="http://localhost/MyApp/" target="_blank" />`

It doesn't seem to make a difference ..

Comment: I've managed to sort out the img tags with using `<base>` and `<img src="images/roundbutton.png">` without the root slash. This does, however, NOT work for stylesheet inclusions in the head tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorted! Was something missing in build config. Thanks for the help!!